# Requirement space of an LP problem

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

Consider an LP problem

Minimize $\sum_{j=1}^{n} c_{j}x_j$

subject to $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mathbf{a}_jx_j \geq \mathbf{b}$ and $x_j \geq 0$ for $j=1,2,...,n$

To solve the problem geometrically, first we plot the $\mathbf{a}_j$ vectors and select the cone area generated by them. The problem has a feasible solution if and only if vector $\mathbf{b}$ belongs to this cone.

However, the procedure to illustrate this cone is not clear to me. As I understand, we select the cone occupied by all the vectors when there are three or more $\mathbf{a}_j$ vectors. How should the area be selected when when we have only $\mathbf{a}_1$ and $\mathbf{a}_2$? Is it region between $\mathbf{a}_1$ and $\mathbf{a}_2$ in anti-clockwise or clockwise direction? And what is the intuition behind this?

Comment: Does the [first picture on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone) help?

Comment: @LinAlg So the cone here refers to a convex cone. Thank you!

Comment: Almost. The vector $b$ has to be less than or equal to an element of the cone. So the feasible region is the convex cone intersected with the set of vectors larger than or equal to $b$. Every point in the intersection corresponds to a feasible $x$.